# Wordpress single post query

Tags: wordpress, post

Trying to display a single post with no title with this code

```
<?php
$post_id = 21;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```

No luck... Doesn't show post at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can follow:

```
  1. Use "Hide Title" plugin.

  2. Add this code:
     if(!is_single())
     {
      wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
      bloginfo( 'name' );
     }

  3. In style.css add this:
     .single #site-title {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To get the title for a post with ID 21:

<?php
$post_21 = get_post(21); 
$title = $post_21->post_title;
$content = $post_21->post_content;
?> 

Alternatively, specify the $output parameter:

<?php
$post_21 = get_post(21, ARRAY_A);
$title = $post_21['post_title'];
$content = $post_21['post_content'];
?>
```